# how to create timeout for a user using st.chat_input()

Tags: python, frontend, chatbot, streamlit, large-language-model

I have created a chatbot using Streamlit where users can input questions and get responses from an LLM model. I want to add an additional feature where the user must type an input within 60 seconds. If they don't, the app should close. If they do, they should receive a response. The same rule applies for the second input.

I used multiple techniques such as while loop for loop etc but failed. below is my original code.

```
user_prompt = st.chat_input()
if user_prompt is not None:
    st.session_state.messages.append({'role':'user','content':user_prompt})
    with st.chat_message('user'):
        st.write(user_prompt)
    with st.chat_message('assistant'):
        with st.spinner('Loading...'):
            response = process_chat(chain, user_prompt, st.session_state.chat_history)
            st.session_state.chat_history.append({'role': 'user', 'content': user_prompt})
            st.session_state.chat_history.append({'role': 'assistant', 'content': response})
            st.write(response)
            st.session_state.messages.append({'role': 'assistant', 'content': response})
            st.session_state.conversation.append({'time':current_time ,'user': user_prompt,'assistant': response})
```